# receiving data in php through jquery ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

i just got the hang of using jquery ajax 
for example, this code sends the contents of the comment box to the php file.

```
    $.post("user_submit.php", {
      comment: $("#comment").text()
    });
```

the question however is how do i receive the data in the user_submit.php file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [`$.post()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post) any data sent like this:

```
$.post("user_submit.php", {
  comment: $("#comment").text()
});
```

is received as such:

```
<?php
$comment = $_POST['comment'];
...
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The basic usage in the PHP side is:

```
echo $_POST["comment"]; // unsafe
```

Remember **basic security** like escaping:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($_POST["comment"]); // minimum
```

Answer (score 1):

It will be in the `$_POST` array:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

...this will show you everything posted to that page.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "how do I receive the output of user_submit.php", then the solution is to use the [callback parameter](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post):

```
$.post("user_submit.php", { comment: $("#comment").text() },
  function(data){
    alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
  });
```

---

If you mean "how do I receive the comment in user_submit.php", then you should use:

`htmlspecialchars($_POST["comment"]);`

Links to php manual pages for [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php), [$_POST](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php).